# How to combine results of 3 Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to make a table per employee that will give the information per employee that was present/absent/work from home.For that I am writing a SQL query that is fetching the records using JOINS. However, I am writing 3 Join statements that are returning me data separately. How can I write a query that will return the results of the 3 subsequent joins in one single (SELECT)query? Here are the Join statements:

```
Select EmployeeId, Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [Absent]
From Attendances
Left Join Employees
On Employees.EmployeeId = Attendances.EmpID And Attendances.IsAbsent = 1 and Employees.Name = 'John'
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2016-06-19 10:00:00.000' 
Group By EmployeeId, Employees.Name

select Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [Present]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsAbsent = 0
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name

select Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [WorkFromHome]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsWorkFromHome = 1
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name
```

The current output that I am getting is:
Name|Present, Name|Absent, Name|WorkFromHome
But I want it as:
Name|Present|Absent|WorkFromHome

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL`

Comment: tried union but the results come in rows.. I don't want that..

Comment: Ah, I think you mean combine them as columns `Name, Absent, Present, WorkFromHome`

Comment: @Sami Yes exactly :)

Comment: Use `Subqueries` instead of `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Subqueries` to get your desired outputs:

```
SELECT T1.ID,
       T1.Name,
       T1.[Absent],
       T2.[Present],
       T3.[WorkFromHome]
FROM
(
select ID, Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [Absent]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsAbsent = 1
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name, ID
) T1 JOIN
(
select ID, Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [Present]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsAbsent = 0
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name, ID
) T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID JOIN
(
select ID, Employees.Name, COUNT(*) [WorkFromHome]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsWorkFromHome = 1
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name, ID
) T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID;
```

Comment: Your query is working fine. Although I am facing an issue.. There are employees who haven't been absent even once or there are employees who haven't worked from home once so there records don't show up in the joins.. Is there a way where I can show their records too by either showing value 0 or anything like that. I am not using Employee.Name in the Where clause instead I am checking for all employees.

Comment: @DelMonte Join them with your employees table and use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I tried that but the problem is it returns Employee ID too as NULL.. Any way to sort this out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION or UNION ALL. For Example

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = 'Mohit'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = 'Jhon'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = 'Jeni'
```

UNION ALL will return unique records. However UNION will return all the record.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION ALL to get combined data like this

```
select Employees.Name, 'A' Attendance, COUNT(*) [Count]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsAbsent = 1
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and 
Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name
UNION ALL
select Employees.Name, 'P' Attendance, COUNT(*) [Count]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsAbsent = 0
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and 
Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name
UNION ALL
select Employees.Name, 'WFH' Attendance, COUNT(*) [Count]
from Employees
Inner Join Attendances
On Employees.UserId = Attendances.EmpID and Attendances.IsWorkFromHome = 1
Where CAST(Attendances.InDateTime as Date) >= '2017-06-19 10:00:00.000' and 
Employees.Name='John'
Group By Employees.Name
```

Comment: are you sure the result will be in the format: Name|Present|Absent|WorkFromHome and not in 'row' format